# Is it possible for a Jordan curve in the plane to enclose a set with area zero?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, inequality, plane-curves

I read about the Isoperimetric Inequality the other day. It says that for any Jordan curve,
$$
\frac{4 \pi A}{L^{2}} \leq 1,
$$
where $ L $ is the length of the curve and $ A $ is the area of the region that it encloses. Is it possible for this quotient to be zero (i.e., $ A = 0 $)?

Comment: You imply that the quotient being zero requires $A$ to be $0$, which as Haskell Curry points out is impossible. It *is* possible though for $L$ to be infinite (and $A$ finite), which could also be taken to make the quotient $0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible. The interior region of any Jordan curve in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ is a non-empty open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $, so has area $ > 0 $. The Jordan Curve Theorem makes this quite clear:

> **Jordan Curve Theorem** Let $ \gamma $ be a Jordan curve in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $. Then its complement $ \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \gamma $ consists of exactly two non-empty connected open subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $, one of which is bounded and the other unbounded. We call the bounded connected component the **interior** and the unbounded connected component the **exterior**.

Let me add to what Chris has mentioned in his valuable comment above. If we consider only rectifiable Jordan curves (i.e., those Jordan curves for which $ L < \infty $), we can make the ratio $ \dfrac{4 \pi A}{L^{2}} $ as close to $ 0 $ as desired.

---

**Example (Koch Snowflake)**

Let $ (\gamma_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ be the well-known sequence of Jordan curves whose pointwise limit is the [Koch Snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake). The first four iterations, $ \gamma_{0} $, $ \gamma_{1} $, $ \gamma_{2} $ and $ \gamma_{3} $, are displayed below.

[image: First four iterations of Koch Snowflake]

Let $ (A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ and $ (L_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ denote, respectively, the sequence of enclosed areas and the sequence of lengths corresponding to $ (\gamma_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $. Then
\begin{align}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}: \quad
A_{n} &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{20}
\left[ 8 - 3 \left( \frac{4}{9} \right)^{n} \right] s^{2}, \\
L_{n} &= 3 \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^{n} s,
\end{align}
where $ s $ is the length of one side of the initial equilateral triangle $ \gamma_{0} $. As
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} A_{n} = \frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{5} \cdot s^{2} \quad \text{and} \quad
\lim_{n \to \infty} L_{n} = \infty,
$$
we see that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4 \pi A_{n}}{L_{n}^{2}} = 0 $.

Comment: could you please give me a reference to the proof?

Comment: @MichaelTouitou: Sure. Please see [Ryuji Maehara’s proof](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/maehara.pdf).